# Find Neighbors of Different Type in Carousel List for Pair of the Same Type (Circular List)

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, logic, enumeration

I have a collection that behaves like a carousel i.e.: the last item is followed by the first item. In this collection (List of IdentifiedAnimal), there is a pair of values that are always together (Mammals). They can be even the first and the last themselves.

My goal is to find the nearest neighbor of one item of the pair (passed as parameter) that is not the other item of the pair (other mammal). i.e: if I pass Dog, it cannot be Cat and vice-versa.

Currently my algorithm seems to be working fine, but maybe there are bugs. Tests are passing for almost all cases. Nevertheless, I was wondering if there is a better and safer way to find the neighbors for a given condition that does not involve such complicated algorithm. Improvements to the logic are also appreciated.
Just to emphasize, Dog and Cat will always be together, neighbors to each other (Mammals).

```
    public Animal GetClosestAnimalNotMammal(IEnumerable<IdentifiedAnimal> identifiedAnimals, Animal currentMammal)
    {
        Animal otherMammal = (currentMammal == Animal.Dog) ? Animal.Cat : Animal.Dog;

        List<IdentifiedAnimal> animalsList = identifiedAnimals.ToList();

        int currentIndex = animalsList.FindIndex(c => c.Animal == currentMammal);
        int lastIndex = animalsList.IndexOf(animalsList.LastOrDefault());

        Dictionary<IdentifiedAnimal, int> animalIndexes = animalsList
            .Where(a => a.Animal != otherMammal && a.Animal != currentMammal)
            .ToDictionary(identifiedAnimal => identifiedAnimal, identifiedAnimal => animalsList.FindIndex(x => x.Animal == identifiedAnimal.Animal));


        int closestIndex = int.MaxValue;
        int maxDistance = int.MaxValue;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<IdentifiedAnimal, int> animalIndex in animalIndexes)
        {
            int usedDistance;

            if ((animalIndex.Value + currentIndex > lastIndex) && (currentIndex - animalIndex.Value > 0) && currentIndex != lastIndex)
            {
                usedDistance = Math.Abs((animalsList.Count - (animalIndex.Value + currentIndex)) -
                                        Math.Abs(animalIndex.Value - currentIndex));
            }
            else if ((animalIndex.Value + currentIndex == lastIndex) && !(currentIndex - animalIndex.Value > 0 && currentIndex != lastIndex))
            {
                usedDistance = Math.Abs(animalsList.Count - (animalIndex.Value + currentIndex));
            }
            else
            {
                usedDistance = Math.Abs(animalIndex.Value - currentIndex);
            }

            if (usedDistance < maxDistance)
            {
                closestIndex = animalIndex.Value;
                maxDistance = usedDistance;
            }
        }

        return animalsList[closestIndex].Animal;
    }

public enum Animal
{
    Alligator,
    Dog,
    Cat,
    Fish,
    Bird,
    Snake
}

public class IdentifiedAnimal
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Animal Animal { get; set; }
}
```

Tests

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private readonly List<IdentifiedAnimal> _identifiedAnimals = new List<IdentifiedAnimal>();

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod01()
    {
        // Arrange
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KLD", Animal = Animal.Alligator});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "XYZ", Animal = Animal.Dog});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "ASO", Animal = Animal.Cat});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "LOL", Animal = Animal.Fish});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KJL", Animal = Animal.Bird});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() { Id = "QPO", Animal = Animal.Snake });
        var expectedAnimal = Animal.Fish;

        // Act
        var closestAnimal = new AnimalFinder().GetClosestAnimalNotMammal(_identifiedAnimals, Animal.Cat);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedAnimal, closestAnimal);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod02()
    {
        // Arrange
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KLD", Animal = Animal.Alligator});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "XYZ", Animal = Animal.Dog});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "ASO", Animal = Animal.Cat});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "LOL", Animal = Animal.Fish});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KJL", Animal = Animal.Bird});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() { Id = "QPO", Animal = Animal.Snake });
        var expectedAnimal = Animal.Alligator;

        // Act
        var closestAnimal = new AnimalFinder().GetClosestAnimalNotMammal(_identifiedAnimals, Animal.Dog);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedAnimal, closestAnimal);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod03()
    {
        // Arrange
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KLD", Animal = Animal.Alligator});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "LOL", Animal = Animal.Fish});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KJL", Animal = Animal.Bird});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "XYZ", Animal = Animal.Dog});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "ASO", Animal = Animal.Cat});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() { Id = "QPO", Animal = Animal.Snake });
        var expectedAnimal = Animal.Bird;

        // Act
        var closestAnimal = new AnimalFinder().GetClosestAnimalNotMammal(_identifiedAnimals, Animal.Dog);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedAnimal, closestAnimal);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod04()
    {
        // Arrange
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KLD", Animal = Animal.Alligator});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "LOL", Animal = Animal.Fish});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KJL", Animal = Animal.Bird});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() { Id = "QPO", Animal = Animal.Snake });
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "XYZ", Animal = Animal.Dog});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "ASO", Animal = Animal.Cat});
        var expectedAnimal = Animal.Alligator;

        // Act
        var closestAnimal = new AnimalFinder().GetClosestAnimalNotMammal(_identifiedAnimals, Animal.Cat);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedAnimal, closestAnimal);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod05()
    {
        // Arrange
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "XYZ", Animal = Animal.Dog});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "ASO", Animal = Animal.Cat});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KLD", Animal = Animal.Alligator});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "LOL", Animal = Animal.Fish});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KJL", Animal = Animal.Bird});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() { Id = "QPO", Animal = Animal.Snake });
        var expectedAnimal = Animal.Snake;

        // Act
        var closestAnimal = new AnimalFinder().GetClosestAnimalNotMammal(_identifiedAnimals, Animal.Dog);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedAnimal, closestAnimal);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod06()
    {
        // Arrange
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KLD", Animal = Animal.Alligator});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "LOL", Animal = Animal.Fish});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KJL", Animal = Animal.Bird});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "ASO", Animal = Animal.Cat});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "XYZ", Animal = Animal.Dog});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() { Id = "QPO", Animal = Animal.Snake });
        var expectedAnimal = Animal.Snake;

        // Act
        var closestAnimal = new AnimalFinder().GetClosestAnimalNotMammal(_identifiedAnimals, Animal.Dog);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedAnimal, closestAnimal);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod07()
    {
        // Arrange
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KLD", Animal = Animal.Alligator});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "LOL", Animal = Animal.Fish});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "ASO", Animal = Animal.Cat});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "XYZ", Animal = Animal.Dog});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KJL", Animal = Animal.Bird});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() { Id = "QPO", Animal = Animal.Snake });
        var expectedAnimal = Animal.Bird;

        // Act
        var closestAnimal = new AnimalFinder().GetClosestAnimalNotMammal(_identifiedAnimals, Animal.Dog);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedAnimal, closestAnimal);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod08()
    {
        // Arrange
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "ASO", Animal = Animal.Cat});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KLD", Animal = Animal.Alligator});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "LOL", Animal = Animal.Fish});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KJL", Animal = Animal.Bird});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() { Id = "QPO", Animal = Animal.Snake });
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "XYZ", Animal = Animal.Dog});
        var expectedAnimal = Animal.Snake;

        // Act
        var closestAnimal = new AnimalFinder().GetClosestAnimalNotMammal(_identifiedAnimals, Animal.Dog);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedAnimal, closestAnimal);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod09()
    {
        // Arrange
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "ASO", Animal = Animal.Cat});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KLD", Animal = Animal.Alligator});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "LOL", Animal = Animal.Fish});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KJL", Animal = Animal.Bird});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() { Id = "QPO", Animal = Animal.Snake });
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "XYZ", Animal = Animal.Dog});
        var expectedAnimal = Animal.Alligator;

        // Act
        var closestAnimal = new AnimalFinder().GetClosestAnimalNotMammal(_identifiedAnimals, Animal.Cat);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedAnimal, closestAnimal);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod10()
    {
        // Arrange
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "ASO", Animal = Animal.Cat});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "XYZ", Animal = Animal.Dog});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KLD", Animal = Animal.Alligator});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "LOL", Animal = Animal.Fish});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() {Id = "KJL", Animal = Animal.Bird});
        _identifiedAnimals.Add(new IdentifiedAnimal() { Id = "QPO", Animal = Animal.Snake });
        var expectedAnimal = Animal.Snake;

        // Act
        var closestAnimal = new AnimalFinder().GetClosestAnimalNotMammal(_identifiedAnimals, Animal.Cat);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedAnimal, closestAnimal);
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *nearest*? Nearest index?

Comment: Yes, I would say so. Not being sarcastic, serious question, but if not the index, what else could it be? Check the tests, they are quite straightforward. @InBetween

Answer (score 0):

Not meaning to be sarcastic, but, isn't this problem much easier to solve? I'm having a hard time trying to comrehend why the need of dictionaries, for eaches, etc. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

```
public static bool TryFindNearestTo<T>
    (this IList<T> source, 
     T item, 
     T itemToExcludeFromSearch, 
     out T nearest)
{
    var indexOfItem = source.IndexOf(item);

    if (indexOfItem < 0)
    {
        //item is not found in source. Search fails.
        nearest = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    var indexAfter = indexOfItem == source.Count - 1 ? 
        0 :
        indexOfItem + 1;

    var indexBefore = indexOfItem == 0 ?
        source.Count - 1 :
        indexOfItem - 1;

    //Assert preconditions
    Debug.Assert(source[indexAfter].Equals(itemToExcludeFromSearch) ||
                 source[indexBefore].Equals(itemToExcludeFromSearch));

    nearest = source[indexAfter].Equals(itemToExcludeFromSearch) ?
        source[indexBefore] :
        source[indexAfter];

    return true;
}
```

Your current problem definition is incomplete. What should the method do if:

1. The specified `item` is not found in `source`.
2. What happens if neither neighbor is the item excluded from the search?

If those two scenarios are not possible, then you should *assert* them in your code because its a precondition that must be met in order for the method to work correctly. If they conditions are possible, then you need to verify them and return something sensible if they are not met. In my case, for illustration purposes, I'm mixing up both cases:

1. The `TrySomething` pattern, where the returned value indicates if the search was succesful and the result is an `out` parameter solves the first issue.
2. The `Debug.Assert` solves the latter one.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to get the Animal(not mammal) that is closest to the passed Animal (mammal). To do so, the index of the Animal (not mammal) needs to be found (or maybe not, that's why I asked). The thing is my input is a list of animals and the mammal to be checked. The output needs to be an Animal (not mammal). I appreciate the effort, but I'd say applying that to my solution would be about the same, no?

Comment: Let me put it like this, I'm looking for the best and clearest solution that solves the unit tests.

Comment: @gcbs_fln You've stated that in the carrousel there is a *pair* of mammals. A pair means `2`. All other animals are therefore not mammals. If both mammals are always together, then the nearest non mammal neighbor must always be one of the following two: the previous animal or the next animal, whichever of the two isn't a mammal. Thats all this method does.

Comment: That's good. I might end up using that in the absence of a better answer. Was actually looking for something that could be done directly into the collection, using Linq. But that's good enough. By the way, the What-If items are not a requirement, but since it's cheap to have them, I'll change my approach to yours. Thanks